# Whats the best way to invoke same function multiple times in Powershell with different input

Tags: powershell

I wish to invoke this Set-FixedVariable multiple times with different input but i only manage to execute it one time when I call DeclareFixedVariables why is that?

```
Function DeclareFixedVariables
{
    try
    {
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixModelName'-value $ModelName -size 30
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixMasterSetId' -value $ReturnMessage.MasterSetID -size 36
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixModelversionId'-value $ModelversionID -size 36
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixStartDateStr' -value $StartDateStr -size 23
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixCreateDate' -value $CreateDateStr -size 23
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixModelChangeDate' -value $ModelChangeDate -size 23
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixModelOwner' -value $ModelProperties.UserId -size 6
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixChangeId' -value $ModelProperties.ChangeId -size 10
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixChangeUser' -value $ModelProperties.UserId -size 10
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixAfBolag' -value $afBolag -size 2
        Set-FixedVariable -name 'fixThBolag' -value $thBolag -size 2
    }catch
    {
        Write-Log -Message "***Invoking Set-FixedVariable failed***" -Path $LogFile -Level Info
    }
}

function Set-FixedVariable 
{

    param( [parameter(mandatory)][string]$name,
           [parameter(mandatory)][string]$value,
           [parameter(mandatory)][int]$size
    )

    $sb = [System.Text.Stringbuilder]::new( ' ' * $size )
    [void]$sb.Insert(0, $value)

    Set-Variable -Name $name -Value $sb.ToString().Substring(0, $size) -Scope Script -Force

    return $value

}
```

Comment: Your `Function DeclareFixedVariables` needs a `param`-block, like the other function, that contains all the variables you use in that function. Then the best way to execute this function multiple times with different input would be an array of hashtables or `PsCustomObjects` that has alle the needed values stored , so that you can execute the function `foreach` hashtable...

Comment: I have a fix for your issue of 'not setting variables for all values' but I really cannot understand what your `Set-FixedVariable` function is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, the only real issue I'm seeing is that all of your variables are set using `Set-FixedVariable` with only one `try/catch` block, meaning that PowerShell will process each one, line by line, and then stop when the first one fails.

It would be better to handle that with a `forEach` loop, like this.

```
Function DeclareFixedVariables
{

    $VariableSettings = @(
        @{Name='fixModelName';Value=$ModelName;Size=30},
        @{Name='fixMasterSetId';Value=$ReturnMessage.MasterSetID;Size=36},
        @{Name='fixModelversionId';Value=$ModelversionID;Size=23}
    )

    forEach($variableSetting in $VariableSettings){
        try{
            Set-FixedVariable @variableSetting
        }
        catch{
            Write-Log -Message "***Invoking Set-FixedVariable failed for $($VariableSetting.Name) with value $($VariableSetting.Value)***" -Path $LogFile -Level Info
        }
    }

}
```

From a code review standard this is probably easier to read (especially if you tweak the layout a bit) and this way the code will execute on each item even if one of them fails.

Next step: You might want to double-check your assumptions for what `Set-FixedVariable` is meant to do.  It is very puzzling, why would it be helpful to have an array with a number of spaces in it before the value?